# Using SWITCH statement in an ARRAY Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

I've tried putting switch in my code in my model page but it gives me server error or maybe my syntax is wrong. What I want to do is whenever the value of `degree` is equal to a specific value it will post or save it to the database with the corresponding name.

Here's what I did in my Model Page:

```
public function changeNow() {
    $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'degree' => $this->input->post('degree'),

        switch($this->input->post('degree')){
            case 'POST-BACC':
                'high_degree_post_bacc'=>$this->input->post('high_degree_post_bacc');
                break;
            case 'LLB':
                'high_degree_llb'=>$this->input->post('high_degree_llb');
                break;
            case 'MD':
                'high_degree_md'=>$this->input->post('high_degree_md');
                break;
        }
    );

    $this->db->update('table_degree', $data); 
}
```

If I delete the switch, it runs. When I put it, it gives error.

First Try: I did what @Marc said

```
 switch($this->input->post('degree')){

    case 'POST-BACC':
       $data['high_degree_post_bacc']=>$this->input->post('high_degree_post_bacc');
            break;                    }     //no luck: still got server error
```

Answer (score 0):

`switch('$this->input->post('degree'){`

you have a `'` in front of your variable  and missing a `)`

should be
`switch($this->input->post('degree')){`

you're also trying to use a switch statement inside of an array.

try doing something like

`case 'POST-BACC':
   $data['high_degree_post_bacc'] = $this->input->post('high_degree_post_bacc');
break;`

this is the full answer:  try this one

```
public function changeNow() {
    $data = array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'degree' => $this->input->post('degree'),
        );

    switch($this->input->post('degree')){
        case 'POST-BACC':
            $data['high_degree_post_bacc'] = $this->input->post('high_degree_post_bacc');
            break;
        case 'LLB':
            $data['high_degree_llb'] = $this->input->post('high_degree_llb');
            break;
        case 'MD':
            $data['high_degree_md'] = $this->input->post('high_degree_md');
            break;
    }

    $this->db->update('table_degree', $data); 
}
```

Comment: sorry for slight mistake, I did what you said(see my edit First Try above) but still no luck. What do you think?

Comment: whats your error?  did you take the switch out of the array assignment?

Comment: Server Error. I doesn't load. I thinks the syntax is the error here.